# Add Link to Content that was changed via CSS?

Tags: css

I changed the footer text of my page. What's the best way to get "Website.de" to be a link?
I am aware that it is not possible in CSS. I don't want to change the HTML of my Theme, so I need to use JavaScript, But I've never used it before.

```
.footer p {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.footer p:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "© 2020 Name. Erstellt von Website.de";
}
```

Comment: That is not possible with CSS pseudo elements.

Comment: it has to be programmed into the footer with html. it can not be done through CSS. The Html code for it is the normal `<a href=""> </a>`code.

Comment: That is not possible with CSS. Use HTML or Javascript.

Comment: Jea I am aware that it is not possible in CSS.
I dont whant to change the HTML of my Theme, so I need to use Javascript. But I never used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't manipulate :after, because it's not technically part of the DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript.
I am afraid without HTML there is no chance of changing that directly.

Comment: Damn. That is sad.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the website.de to be a link then style it just like the style you are using to the other text